# SQL Server: two similar queries in the same time

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

Background: One heavy query will cost 5s.  I use with(nolock) for every tables.  The difference of them is the "select rows".

I open two windows in sqlserver and set waitfor time to ensure they can start together and I guess it will cost about 5s.

However it always costs 9s~11s.

I also try it in code but still it also always costs 9s~11s.

Why can't they run in parallel?

Thanks.

Comment: `The difference of them is the "select rows"`. what is `them` ?

Comment: did you use indexes?

Comment: Them:  the two similar queries.

Comment: I use many indexes in the relevant tables.  My question is **not** why one query performs bad. I want to find out why they start in the same time but it  seems they run in serial.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries may run in parallel, but it doesn't mean they will have a duration similar to if only one query ran.

Each query consumes CPU, memory and IO. Each query can already use parallelism. So if you add a parallel query and the system for the first query is fully busy, the total execution time may be as if to run the queries in serial.

Comment: I think you are right.  The server always processes a heavy IO.